# postgresql find similar word groups

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, string-matching, varchar

I have a table1 containing a column A, where ~100,000 strings (varchar) are stored. Unfortunately, each string has multiple words which are seperated with spaces. Further they have different length, i.e. one string can consist of 3 words while an other string contains 7 words.

Then I have a column B stored in a second table2 which contains only 100 strings in the same manner. Hence, multiple words per string, seperated by spaces.

The target is, to look how likely a record of Column B is matching with probably multiple records of column A based on the words. The result should also have a ranking. I was thinking of using full text search in a loop but I don't know how to do this, or if there is a proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can "tturn" table to a dictionary to use full text for ranking here. But you can query it with some primityve ranking quite easily, eg:

```
t=# with a(a) as (values('a b c'),('a c d'),('b e f'),('r b t'),('q w'))
, b(i,b) as (values(1,'a b'), (2,'e'), (3,'b'))
, p as (select unnest(string_to_array(b.b,' ')) arr,i from b)
select a phrases,arr match_words,count(1) over (partition by arr) words_in_matches, count(1) over (partition by i) matches,i from a left join p on a.a like '%'||arr||'%';
 phrases | match_words | words_in_matches | matches | i
---------+-------------+------------------+---------+---
 r b t   | b           |                6 |       5 | 1
 a b c   | b           |                6 |       5 | 1
 b e f   | b           |                6 |       5 | 1
 a b c   | a           |                2 |       5 | 1
 a c d   | a           |                2 |       5 | 1
 b e f   | e           |                1 |       1 | 2
 r b t   | b           |                6 |       3 | 3
 a b c   | b           |                6 |       3 | 3
 b e f   | b           |                6 |       3 | 3
 q w     |             |                1 |       1 |
(10 rows)
```

- phrases are rows from your big table.
- match_words are tokens from your small table (splitted by spaces)
- words_in_matches amount of tokens in phrases
- matches is amount of matches in big table phrases from small table phrases
- i index of phrase from small table

So you can order by third or fourth column to get some sort of ranking...

Comment: thanks for your answer. since I'm fairly new to pgsql I simply don't understand it. what do you mean with tokens?

Comment: tokens are words, in this case I used letter separated by space for simplicity. read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#textsearch-parsing-documents for concept